# CSS/HTML - Centering Absolute Positioned Image

Tags: html, css, center, css-position

I've been at this for quite a while now, and can't seem to get a grip on it. I was wondering how to make my ".logo" class centered?

```
#wrap {
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
    background: url(../images/logo.png);
    width: 269px;
    height: 126px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
}        

<div id="wrap">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div id="nav"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if u want the logo div centered remove the position absolute and add text-align:center; if you want the logo image to be centered inside the div, just add background-position: center center;

Comment: text-align is irrelevant. I need to position a image.

Comment: I need it to be absolute, so it can be on top of my navigation bar.

Comment: you also need position: relative for #wrap for the logo to be relative to it

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a fixed width container hold the absolute element, all you actually need to do is add:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -134px;
```

to .logo and you're good. The margin-left should be 1/2 of the absolute element's width. This, assuming you are only going for a horizontal center. Vertical would work similar with a top/margin-top, but that would require a fixed height.

Comment: very straight forward!

Answer (score 1):

just add background-position: center center;
and define the background better:

```
background-image: url() 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center center; // you can have top bottom left right as well
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `div` with the `right` and `left` properties the same, put my objects in the div, and either set the `margin-right` and `margin-left` properties for the child objects to `auto` or set the `text-align` attribute to `center`.  This should center most objects.

BTW, be careful with absolute positioning.  It can get ugly.

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions. A word about absolute though, 'bitch' it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/UY2FC/4/

http://jsfiddle.net/UY2FC/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/UY2FC/1/

each one does the same job, but with subtle differences.

Though, what's with z-index? are you masking something?

Answer (score 0):

use margin:0 auto;

This logo is horizontally centered by setting its right and left margin widths to "auto". This is the preferred way to accomplish horizontal centering with CSS

example css

```
          .logo{
                background: url(../images/logo.png);
                width: 269px;
                height: 126px;
                z-index: 1000;
                margin:0px auto; //or margin:0 auto;
                 } 

                }
```